# Angular Pwa execute requests twice

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have the following problem I have a pwa with angular and I have a problem when I call the backend, when calling a backend route it does it twice and I can't find the solution

My ngs-config.json

````
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "/manifest.json"
        ],
        "urls":[
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 20,
        "maxAge": "1h",
        "timeout": "5s",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: What endpoint is called?

Comment: I have my own backend developed in node

Comment: Are you seeing the duplicate call in the backend logs or in the browser's devtools?

Comment: If I was analyzing the backend log and I have only one call, the chrome inspector shows me two but I already understood that it is the work of the serviceworker